# Iterating through nested list/dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I am trying to parse a yaml file - https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/master/semantic_conventions/resource/cloud.yaml

I am using the following code

```
with open('cloud.yaml') as f:
    my_dict = yaml.safe_load(f)

print(my_dict)
```

Which generates the following dictionary

```
{'groups': [{'id': 'cloud', 'prefix': 'cloud', 'brief': 'A cloud infrastructure (e.g. GCP, Azure, AWS)\n', 'attributes': [{'id': 'provider', 'type': {'allow_custom_values': True, 'members': [{'id': 'AWS', 'value': 'aws', 'brief': 'Amazon Web Services'}, {'id': 'Azure', 'value': 'azure', 'brief': 'Microsoft Azure'}, {'id': 'GCP', 'value': 'gcp', 'brief': 'Google Cloud Platform'}]}, 'brief': 'Name of the cloud provider.\n', 'examples': 'gcp'}, {'id': 'account.id', 'type': 'string', 'brief': 'The cloud account ID used to identify different entities.\n', 'examples': ['opentelemetry']}, {'id': 'region', 'type': 'string', 'brief': 'A specific geographical location where different entities can run.\n', 'examples': ['us-central1']}, {'id': 'zone', 'type': 'string', 'brief': 'Zones are a sub set of the region connected through low-latency links.\n', 'note': 'In AWS, this is called availability-zone.\n', 'examples': ['us-central1-a']}]}]}
```

I want to iterate through the elements and extract the following values

1. id - cloud
2. all attributes -> id - provider; id - account.id ; id -region ; id - zone
3. members - aws, azure, gcp

I am trying to go through all key values using below code

```
for groups in my_dict.values():
    print(groups)
```

Output is

```
[{'id': 'cloud', 'prefix': 'cloud', 'brief': 'A cloud infrastructure (e.g. GCP, Azure, AWS)\n', 'attributes': [{'id': 'provider', 'type': {'allow_custom_values': True, 'members': [{'id': 'AWS', 'value': 'aws', 'brief': 'Amazon Web Services'}, {'id': 'Azure', 'value': 'azure', 'brief': 'Microsoft Azure'}, {'id': 'GCP', 'value': 'gcp', 'brief': 'Google Cloud Platform'}]}, 'brief': 'Name of the cloud provider.\n', 'examples': 'gcp'}, {'id': 'account.id', 'type': 'string', 'brief': 'The cloud account ID used to identify different entities.\n', 'examples': ['opentelemetry']}, {'id': 'region', 'type': 'string', 'brief': 'A specific geographical location where different entities can run.\n', 'examples': ['us-central1']}, {'id': 'zone', 'type': 'string', 'brief': 'Zones are a sub set of the region connected through low-latency links.\n', 'note': 'In AWS, this is called availability-zone.\n', 'examples': ['us-central1-a']}]}]
```

I wanted to print all values individually, example - cloud, A cloud infrastructure (e.g. GCP, Azure, AWS)\n etc

Output I need is to print below values:

```
cloud, A cloud infrastructure (e.g. GCP, Azure, AWS).
cloud.provider,, Name of the cloud provider.
cloud.provider.member, AWS, Amazon Web Services
cloud.provider.member, azure, Microsoft Azure
cloud.provider.member, GCP, Google Cloud Platform
cloud.account.id, string, The cloud account ID used to identify different entities.
cloud.region, string, A specific geographical location where different entities can run.    
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the structure/output you want to put those values into?  You already have all of the data you're asking about, so it's just a matter of putting it into some other shape.

Comment: @Samwise thanks for your reply. I am having a hard time to iterate through the output dictionary. This looks like a nested dictionary with child lists/dictionaries.  print(my_dict["groups"][0]["id"]) gives output as cloud

Comment: @Samwise I updated the question with more details

Comment: Please provide an example of the output you expect from the input you already provided.

Comment: @Grismar - thanks for your help. I added an expected output section in the question

Comment: From that example, where is `string` for the `cloud.provider` coming from? The `type` for that dictionary isn't `string`, but instead defines a more complicated structure with `allow_custom_values`?

Comment: @Grismar Lets ignore cloud.provider for now, its a complex case. I edited the expected output again.

Comment: Now, where is the `' - '` coming from, is that something you'd want for anything that doesn't have a string for `'type'` attributes? Why are AWS and azure in there, but GCP isn't?

Comment: Your example output isn't something that can be derived from the input by simple iteration; you're treating the keys differently according to rules that you haven't explained.

Comment: I can partially do it via below code

for groups in my_dict.values():
    print(groups)
    for i in range(len(my_dict["groups"][0]["attributes"])):
        print(my_dict["groups"][0]["attributes"][i]["id"])
        print(my_dict["groups"][0]["attributes"][i]["type"])
        print(my_dict["groups"][0]["attributes"][i]["brief"])
        print(my_dict["groups"][0]["attributes"][i]["examples"])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also can be implemented in a generic way, verifying if the value in 'type' is a dict instance:

Supposing that the variable parsed_dict has the result after parse the jaml file:

```
def remove_end_of_line_char(line_text):
    if len(line_text) > 0 and line_text[-1] == '\n':
        line_text = line_text[:-1]

    return line_text


data_groups = parsed_dict["groups"]
for group in data_groups:
    msg = remove_end_of_line_char(f"{group['id']}, {group['brief']}")
    print(msg)
    attributes_list = group["attributes"]
    for attribute in attributes_list:
        attr_type = attribute['type']
        if isinstance(attr_type, dict):
            print(f"{group['id']}.{attribute['id']},, {remove_end_of_line_char(attribute['brief'])}")
            cloud_provider_member_prefix = f"{group['id']}.{attribute['id']}.member, "
            for member in attr_type['members']:
                print(f"{cloud_provider_member_prefix}{member['id']}, {member['brief']}")
        else:
            msg = remove_end_of_line_char(f"{group['id']}.{attribute['id']}, {attribute['type']}, {attribute['brief']}")
            print(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your output dictionary. I made it readable

```
myDict = {
'groups': [
    {
        'id': 'cloud', 
        'prefix': 'cloud', 
        'brief': 'A cloud infrastructure (e.g. GCP, Azure, AWS)\n', 
        'attributes': [
            {
                'id': 'provider', 
                'type': {
                    'allow_custom_values': True, 
                    'members': [
                        {
                            'id': 'AWS', 
                            'value': 'aws', 
                            'brief': 'Amazon Web Services'
                            
                        }, 
                        {
                            'id': 'Azure', 
                            'value': 'azure', 
                            'brief': 'Microsoft Azure'
                            
                        }, 
                        {
                            'id': 'GCP', 
                            'value': 'gcp', 
                            'brief': 'Google Cloud Platform'
                            
                        }
                    ]
                    
                }, 
                'brief': 'Name of the cloud provider.\n',
                'examples': 'gcp'
                
            }, 
            {
                'id': 'account.id', 
                'type': 'string', 
                'brief': 'The cloud account ID used to identify different entities.\n', 
                'examples': ['opentelemetry']}, 
                {
                    'id': 'region', 
                    'type': 'string', 
                    'brief': 'A specific geographical location where different entities can run.\n',
                    'examples': ['us-central1']
                    
                },
                {
                    'id': 'zone', 
                    'type': 'string', 
                    'brief': 'Zones are a sub set of the region connected through low-latency links.\n',
                    'note': 'In AWS, this is called availability-zone.\n',
                    'examples': ['us-central1-a']
                    
                }
        ]
    }
]

}
```

Now we can see it clearly.

```
for v in myDict['groups'][0].items():
    print(v)
```

Output:

```
('id', 'cloud')
('prefix', 'cloud')
('brief', 'A cloud infrastructure (e.g. GCP, Azure, AWS)\n')
('attributes', [{'id': 'provider', 'type': {'allow_custom_values': True, 'members': [{'id': 'AWS', 'value': 'aws', 'brief': 'Amazon Web Services'}, {'id': 'Azure', 'value': 'azure', 'brief': 'Microsoft Azure'}, {'id': 'GCP', 'value': 'gcp', 'brief': 'Google Cloud Platform'}]}, 'brief': 'Name of the cloud provider.\n', 'examples': 'gcp'}, {'id': 'account.id', 'type': 'string', 'brief': 'The cloud account ID used to identify different entities.\n', 'examples': ['opentelemetry']}, {'id': 'region', 'type': 'string', 'brief': 'A specific geographical location where different entities can run.\n', 'examples': ['us-central1']}, {'id': 'zone', 'type': 'string', 'brief': 'Zones are a sub set of the region connected through low-latency links.\n', 'note': 'In AWS, this is called availability-zone.\n', 'examples': ['us-central1-a']}])
```

Now extract data like this. But you can get all values in one for loop

```
data = myDict['groups'][0]
id = data['id']
brief = data['brief']
attr = data['attributes']
mems = attr[0]['type']['members']

print(f"{id},{brief})    

for member in mems:
    print(f"cloud.provider.member.{member['value']}, {member['brief']}")
```

Output:

```
cloud,A cloud infrastructure (e.g. GCP, Azure, AWS)

cloud.provider.member.aws, Amazon Web Services
cloud.provider.member.azure, Microsoft Azure
cloud.provider.member.gcp, Google Cloud Platform
```